# Я не могу запустить бота на хостинге pythonanywhere помогите

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-3.6, pythonanywhere

> Я всегда получаю эту ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 992, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 505, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 170, in make_request
    async with session.post(
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1194, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 578, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 911, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1235, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1204, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1000, in _wrap_create_connection

    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Fill123456/OneGo/Bot_Onego/Run.py", line 24, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/Fill123456/OneGo/Bot_Onego/Run.py", line 18, in main
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 1284, in delete_webhook
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 492, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 254, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
  File "/home/Fill123456/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 177, in make_request
    raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message=f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]
```

Answer (score 0):

aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default **[Network is unreachable]**

aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default **[Network is unreachable]**

OSError: [Errno 101] **Network is unreachable**

Выхода в сеть нету в окружение где запускаете.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Проблема заключается в том что я пытаюсь запустить бота на онлайн хостинге где по идеи всегда должен быть выход в интернет. Могу еще добавить что у меня уже есть бот который хоститься на pythonanywhere только он написан на библиотеке Telebot и с ним все отлично, работает .